# Show that $T\in B(X,Y)$ is invertible iff $T$ is injective, has a closed range and $T^*$ is injective.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be banach spaces and $T\in B(X,Y)$.
Show that:

$T$ is invertible iff $T$ is injective, has a closed range and $T^*$ is injective.

My trial:
First side: => if T is invertible then T is injective
. Now, let $y_1^*,y_2^* \in Y^*$ such that $T^* y_1^*=T^* y_2^*$, we aim to show that $y_1^* = y_2^*$.

By definition we have: $ y_1^* T=T^* y_1^* = T^* y_2^* = y_2^* T$ so we can multiple both sided by $T^{-1} $ (since it is invertible by assumption). And get what is needed.
How to conclude that $T$ has a closed range?

I have a problem in proving the other side =>, using the assumptions.

Can you kindly evaluate my method in the first side, and help with the second side.

Comment: You mean $y_1^*T=T^*y_1^*=T^*y_2^*=y_2^*T$ not $T^*y_1^*=y_1^*T=T^*y_2^*=y_2^*T$.  Use Hahn-Banach to get $T^*$ surjective implies $T$ injective.

Comment: '$T$ surjective and has closed range' does not make sense.

Comment: Hi @Kavi Rama Murthy, i did not undersatnd ..

Comment: $T$ surjective means $T(X)=Y$. And $Y$ is always closed in $Y$.

Comment: Oh i made a mistake in my question, i'll fix it @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T$ is invertible then $T: X \to Y$ is a bijection and $T$ has  a bounded inverse $: Y \to X$. It is obvious that $T$ is injective and its range $Y$ is closed. To show that $T^{*}$ is injective let $T^{*}y^{*}=0$. Then $T^{*}y^{*}(x)=0$ for all $x$. This means $y^{*}(Tx)=0$ for all $x$. But $T$ is onto $Y$ so $y^{*}=0$.

Converse: Suppose $T$ is injective , has closed range and $T^{*}$ is injective. The range of $T$ is dense: If it is not then Hahn Banach Theorem gives a  non-zero $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$ which vanishes on he range of $T$. But then $T^{*}y^{*}(x)=y^{*}(Tx)=0$ for all $x$ , so $T^{*}y^{*}=0$. This contradicts then fact that $T^{*}$ is injective. Since the range of $T$ is closed and dense it is equal to $Y$. Now Open Mapping Theorem shows that $T$ has a boundecd inverse.

Comment: I think this answer was given before the question was edited, but the question (now) has the condition that $T$ and $T^*$ are injective, not surjective.

Comment: Question completely changed after I posted my answr This is really bad.

Comment: @Bestmat There are still problems with your terminologies. Closed image is not the same as  closed operator (which means that the graph is closed) Your claim that $T$ has closed range because it is continuous is false.

Comment: @Bestmat I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy in the end, you meant "by inverse bounded theorem" not open mapping..?

Comment: @Bestmat Well, many books include boundedness of the inverse as part of Open Mapping Theorem.